# setTimeout stop at 2:00 p.m. and 3:00 p.m

Tags: javascript

I would like to retrieve the value of BTC at 2 p.m. and 3 p.m. via a setTimeout.

How can I set the setTimeout? Am I required to use seconds?

```
function runTimers() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    ...

    setTimeout(() => {
      ...
    }, 1000);
  }, 2000);
}
```

So, the value `1000` = `1 seconde`

I convert `02:00 PM` to minutes? So, the result is `840 minutes`.

Then, I convert `840 minutes` into secondes? So, `50400 secondes` and I add `000` -> `50400000`?

```
function runTimers() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    ...

    setTimeout(() => {
      ...
    }, 50400000);
  }, 54000000);
}
```

Do you agree with me? Is there a simpler solution?

```
function runTimers() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    let val1 = parseFloat(stockObject.p).toFixed(2);
    let price = parseFloat(stockObject.p).toFixed(2);

    stockPriceElementsec2.innerText = price;
    stockPriceElementsec2.style.color =
      !lastPrice || lastPrice === price
        ? 'black'
        : price > lastPrice
        ? '#AAFF00'
        : 'red';

    lastPrice = price;
    stockObject = null;

    setTimeout(() => {
      let val2 = parseFloat(stockObject.p).toFixed(2);
      let price = parseFloat(stockObject.p).toFixed(2);

      stockPriceElementsec3.innerText = price;
      stockPriceElementsec3.style.color =
        !lastPrice || lastPrice === price
          ? 'black'
          : price > lastPrice
          ? '#AAFF00'
          : 'red';

      lastPrice = price;
      stockObject = null;
    }, 1000);
  }, 2000);
}
```

Here is the complete code => [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-abrrg3?file=script.js).

Comment: In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: What you should probably do is `var threePmToday = ...... var now = new Date(); var delta = threePmToday - now; if (delta > 0) setTimeout(myFunction, convertToMillis(delta));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTimeout` will just run some code after a given delay (in ms), so it is not the right solution if you want to check something at regular intervals.
What you'd rather want to use would probably be `setInterval` which works the exact same way, but the code fires up every X ms.
For instance, you could run this code every hour, and check that the current time is 2pm or 3pm.

```
let runTimers = setInterval(() => {
    let hours = new Date().getHours();
    if (hours < 14 || hours > 15) return; 
    let val1 = parseFloat(stockObject.p).toFixed(2);
    let price = parseFloat(stockObject.p).toFixed(2);

    stockPriceElementsec2.innerText = price;
    stockPriceElementsec2.style.color =
      !lastPrice || lastPrice === price
        ? 'black'
        : price > lastPrice
        ? '#AAFF00'
        : 'red';

    lastPrice = price;
    stockObject = null;
  }, 3600000);
}
```

this does the same thing, except it runs every hour. Let's say you fire it up at 13:01 , it'll show you the value at 14:01 and 15:01 and will show nothing at 16:01.